# Fill MySQL table with the data from CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv, fill

There is a CSV file with the following data:

```
1;8-25-2010;0:05;210;4
2;8-25-2010;2:45;412;5
3;8-25-2010;3:40;300;3
4;8-25-2010;4:45;226;6
5;8-25-2010;5:20;206;4
6;8-25-2010;5:25;216;3
```

And there is MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Schedule` (
  `ID` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Num` INT(10),
  `PlannedDate` DATE,
  `PlannedTime` TIME NOT NULL,
  `resQty` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  `stID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  FOREIGN KEY `stID` (`stID`) REFERENCES Stands (`stID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now I need to fill this table with the data from CSV file. For this I'm using the following code:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE testDB.Schedule;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\temp\\Input.csv'
INTO TABLE testDB.Schedule FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (Num,PlannedDate,PlannedTime,stID,resQty);
```

But the error message says that **"Data truncated for column PlannedDate at row1"**, ErrorNr. 1265. The same error message for all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date has the wrong format, it should be 2012-01-19

Comment: Well, I tried to change the Date format to "2012-01-19" and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck with that date format (which is not the MySQL default), you can load those dates into a temporary variable and then convert it to a date, like this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE testDB.Schedule;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\temp\\Input.csv'
INTO TABLE testDB.Schedule FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(Num,@PlannedDate,PlannedTime,stID,resQty)
SET PlannedDate = STR_TO_DATE(@PlannedDate,'%m-%d-%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
(Num,PlannedDate,PlannedTime,stID,resQty);
```

the two last parameters are reversed: `stID,resQty`

it SHOULD be:

```
resQty, stID
```

This is why you are getting a truncation error.

Comment: I don't think so, because in CSV file I have stdID->resQty. Sorry for not mentioning this.